# How can I get a report from the FAA stating that I haven't had any accidents?

Tags: faa, pilot-certification

To validate my FAA licence in Argentina and fly aircraft with LV tail numbers they require some documents, one of which is a report that states that I haven't been in any accidents. This report must come from the agency that issued my rating, in my case the FAA. I have not found any information on how to request this report from the FAA.

Answer (score 16):

The FAA offers [a dedicated website](https://aie-pa.faa.gov/) for requesting enforcement records at https://aie-pa.faa.gov/.

Additional guidance from the FAA [is available here](https://www.faa.gov/licenses_certificates/airmen_certification/new_verification_info):

> If you require a verification letter of your FAA airman certificate, for a Foreign Civil Aviation Authority, the request must come directly from the Foreign Civil Aviation Authority to the FAA. We will reply only to the official email address for the Foreign Civil Aviation Authority.
>
> To check the validity of certificates for accident, incident and enforcement information visit https://aie-pa.faa.gov/ to submit your request.

The note about requests only being accepted directly from the foreign authority only applies to certificate verification.

I tried this out, and within an hour I got back an official-looking PDF with the FAA seal and a signature:

> Control Number: 2023-xx-xxxxxxx-P
>
> This is in response to your July 26, 2023 request seeking records through FAA’s Accident, Incident and Enforcement (AIE) portal. Specifically, you requested the following pertaining to (MY NAME): 1) basic EIS enforcement action information pertaining to closed investigations only; 2) summary data on any accidents or incidents in the airman’s record (within the AIDS system); 3) CAIS records (Certificate verification).
>
> **A search of the Accident/Incident Data System and Enforcement Information System on July 26, 2023, revealed no Accident/Incident or Enforcement record(s) concerning the above individual.**

(Phew, glad there was nothing there I didn't know about!)